# Displaying Virtual Attribute In CGridView

Tags: php, yii

I have used a `from_date` & `to_date` attributes to search my data and have placed it in the Model as safe attributes. Now I want to display the same `from_date` and `to_date` in the CGridview with other data from the model.

Shouldn't I just be able to use `$data->from_date` in my CGridView?

Model

```
public $from_date;
public $to_date;

public function rules() {
    array('from_date, to_date', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
}

public function search(){
    //....

    if(!empty($this->to_date) && !empty($this->from_date))
    {
        $criteria->addCondition("date($created_date)  >= '$this->from_date' and       date($created_date) <= '$this->to_date'");
    }
    else if(!empty($this->from_date) && empty($this->to_date))
    {
        $criteria->addCondition("date($created_date) >= '$this->from_date'");
    }
    else if(!empty($this->to_date) && empty($this->from_date))
    {
        $criteria->addCondition("date($created_date) <= '$this->to_date'");
    }

    //....
}
```

Controller

```
$model = new Tickets('search');

if (!empty($_GET)) {
    $model->ticket_id = isset($_GET['ticket_id']) ? $_GET['ticket_id'] : '';

    $model->from_date = isset($_GET['from_date']) ? $_GET['from_date'] : '';
    $model->to_date = isset($_GET['to_date']) ? $_GET['to_date'] : '';
}       


$this->render('search', array(
    'model' => $model
));
```

View

```
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView', array(
    'type' => 'striped bordered condensed',
    'dataProvider' => $model->search(),
    'columns' => array(
        array(
            'name' => 'From date',
            'type' => 'html',
            'value' => '$data->from_date',
        ),
    ),
));
```

Comment: I am actually using a dataprovider here. So it is $data->from_date in the Gridview.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following adjustments. I don't see where you specified how the `$_GET` attributes were being set, so I included the standard way of doing it with `CGridView`. Let me know if it works.

Controller:

```
$model = new Tickets('search');
//remove any default values
$model->unsetAttributes();

//set the attributes based on the standard syntax of how CGridview populates GET
if (!empty($_GET['Tickets'])) {
    $model->attributes = $_GET['Tickets'];
}       


$this->render('search', array(
    'model' => $model
));
```

Model: add `ticket_id` to rules, to automatically process set it if present.

```
public function rules() {
    array('from_date, to_date, ticket_id', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
}
```

View:

```
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView', array(
    'type' => 'striped bordered condensed',
    'dataProvider' => $model->search(),
    'filter'=>$model,//should provide default filtering
    'columns' => array(
        array(
            'name' => 'From date',
            'type' => 'html',
            'value' => '$data->from_date',
        ),
    ),
));
```

Side note: Your model's `search` method had huge SQL injection vulnerabilities, but let's solve one problem at a time first.

Comment: I have been setting the $_GET attributes from the search form. Anyway I tried the adjustment but its not working at the moment. Also, I dont see much of a difference between the code I have posted and your's except for the filter. Please do let me know. Thank you.

Comment: Add `print_r($_GET);` somewhere in the view to verify whether or not the GET attributes are actually being set.